# Stopping Form from submitting if not validated

Tags: javascript

I have a form with weights, and I am making sure that each weight is:

1. A number
2. Every weight > 0
3. Sum of all weights = 100.

The below example is just testing 1 and 3:

```
function assertWeightValidity() {

           let weightSum = 0;

           $.each($('[name^=weight_]'), function()
           {
                    chai.assert(isNaN(this.value) === false, 'Weights should be numbers!');
                    let currWeight = Number(this.value);
                    console.log(currWeight);
                    weightSum += currWeight;
                    <!-- assert nothing is zero -->
           });
           console.log(weightSum);
 }

onEnterCalculate("#calculate", assertWeightValidity);
```

and then I have onEnterCalculate function defined as:

```
function onEnterCalculate(selector, assertion) {

    middleware = assertion || null;

    document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
        var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
        if (keyCode == 13) {
            if(middleware) { middleware(); }
            $(selector).click();
        }
    }
}
```

I am a bit of a newbie in JavaScript. I have googled around but I cannot find the solution. What I am trying to achieve is, if chai at any point throws an Error, I do not want to submit the form, I want to alert the user and let them amend what they already inputted in the form. I found that something like that can be achieved with the `preventDefault()` call. Not sure how to grab the event inside of `assertWeightValidity()` (because presumable I would need to generate the event when chai throws an error). What currently happens is that chai throws an Uncaught Exception if the weight is bad, for example 'sadasda' but it conitnues and posts the form anyway.

Thanks

Comment: What is this `chai` plugin you are talking about... is it a validator of sorts? It might be a lot easier if you can actually create a proof-of-concept MCVE. p/s: In JS, comments should be `// ...` or `/* ... */`.

Comment: If there is any function which is handling form submit then there you need to call event.preventDefault() where event need to pass to function as param like you did in `function (evt)` if it is the function then `evt.preventDefault()`

Comment: Oh yes. I do not need to create "middleware" I can just add the onSubmit method. And if chai throws error I prevent default. I just need to be able to catch the error. Hmmm

Comment: I have written a modified logic based on yours, and it seems to be working: do check my answer out :) it contains a proof-of-concept example that you can test, too.

Comment: my code also started working when I removed the HTML comment... :)))))) I am using PyCharm to write this stuff in Flask, and when you are on the html file and do Ctrl + / and you also have javascript tagged with <script>... this is what happens: nothing good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, you give your `form` a `submit` event where you run your validations. If you call `e.preventDefault()` and/or `return false` in that function, it won't submit. Otherwise, it will.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  console.log('preventing submit');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

From there, it is just a matter of validating your code however you want and then calling (or not calling) `preventDefault()` as necessary:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {  
  if (!document.querySelector('input').value) {
    console.log('Must add a value');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <label>Value: <input /></label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you have multiple validation functions that all return a boolean (or better yet, an error message), an easy way to check would be to put them in an array and then use `every()` or `filter()` to see if they are all good.

```js
const checkField = id => !!document.querySelector(`#${id}`).value;

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  if (![checkField('a'), checkField('b'), checkField('c')].every(Boolean)) {
    console.log('All fields must have a value');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <label>Value: <input id="a"/></label>
  <label>Value: <input id="b"/></label>
  <label>Value: <input id="c"/></label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Even better, it can return an error message if it doesn't then you can gather up the error messages with `filter()`:

```js
const checkField = id => document.querySelector(`#${id}`).value ? undefined : `Field "${id}" must have a value`;

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  const errors = [checkField('a'), checkField('b'), checkField('c')].filter(Boolean);
  
  if (errors.length) {
    console.log(errors);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <label>Value: <input id="a"/></label>
  <label>Value: <input id="b"/></label>
  <label>Value: <input id="c"/></label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Finally, since you mentioned throwing errors, if you want it to actually throw errors, you can try catch them and then output those.

```js
const checkField = id => {
  if (!document.querySelector(`#${id}`).value) {
    throw new Error(`Field ${id} must have a value`);
  }
};

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  try {
    checkField('a');
    checkField('b');
    checkField('c');
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <label>Value: <input id="a"/></label>
  <label>Value: <input id="b"/></label>
  <label>Value: <input id="c"/></label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The downside of this though is you can't check multiple things at the same time, since it'll abort on the first error.

Comment: Curious what the one downvote was about. Do I have something wrong somewhere?

Comment: I did not downvote. I upvoted you. This is probably the best answer I ever received, in terms of knowledge that I have gained, in terms of breadth of the answer, etc. Very well done. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is instead of listening to keyboard events, you should simply check the `submit` event fired by the form. It's a very convenient catch all, because any user interaction that triggers form submission (could be the enter key, clicking a submit button, or whatsoever) will be caught by this handler.

Since you did not tag your question with "jQuery" and you seem to be familiar with ES6 syntax, I have formulated my answer using the following assumptions. To get the result you want, it is quite simple:

1. Listen to the form's `submit` event
2. Refactor your `assertWeightValidity()` method so that it throws an error, which we can catch in the submit event handler
3. Call `assertWeightValidity()` in a `try` block
4. If no errors are thrown, we can then submit the form :)

More details for the `assertWeightValidity()` method: you need to (1) first check if the weight input elements have non-empty values that can be parsed into numbers, and (2) you also want to check the sum of these values if they match 100.

1. Use `Array.map()` to iterate through all your input elements and retrieve their value. Before returning, you can already implement the logic to check if they are numbers. When returning, make sure to use the `+` operator to coerce the values to numbers (HTML values are always returned as string!)
2. Use `Array.reduce()` to sum up the array of weights you have
3. Check if the sum matches 100.

A proof-of-concept example is as follow. Test case:

- Leave any of the field blank. Should throw an error because one or more fields cannot be converted into a number
- Use `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` in all 4 input fields. Should throw an error because they don't sum to 100
- Use `25` for each field, that will sum to `100` and you should see a console log informing you that the form is valid and will be submitted.

Note that since I don't know what `chai` is about, I have simply commented the line out:

```js
const customForm = document.getElementById('customForm');
customForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

  // Intercept default form submission
  e.preventDefault();

  // Assert weight validity
  try {
    assertWeightValidity.call(this)
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
    return;
  }

  // Programmatically trigger form submission if no errors are thrown
  console.log('Submitting form now');
  // Uncomment the next line to actually submit the form
  // this.submit();
});

// Returns if the weights are valid or not
function assertWeightValidity() {

  // Get array of all weights
  const weightElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.querySelectorAll('input[name^=weight_]'));

  // Use `Array.map` to check if numbers can be parsed and return an array of weights
  const weightsArray = weightElements.map((weightElement) => {
    // If weight is empty or not a number, we throw an error and exit
    // chai.assert(!isNaN(weight.value), 'Weights should be numbers!');
    if (weightElement.value === '' || isNaN(weightElement.value))
      throw 'Weights should be numbers';
      
    // Otherwise, we return the value
    return +weightElement.value;
    
  });
  
  // Use `Array.reduce` to get the sum of weights
  const totalWeight = weightsArray.reduce((weight, accumulatedWeight) => weight + accumulatedWeight);

  if (totalWeight !== 100)
    throw 'Weights do not add up to 100';
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="customForm">
  <input type="number" name="weight_1" placeholder="Enter a value for weight 1" />
  <input type="number" name="weight_2" placeholder="Enter a value for weight 2" />
  <input type="number" name="weight_3" placeholder="Enter a value for weight 3" />
  <input type="number" name="weight_4" placeholder="Enter a value for weight 4" />
  <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: oh dear, two absolutely amazing answers to the same question. I feel like flipping a coin to choose one :) Thank you very much, using map and reduce is very elegant :)